# Specific CSS on Wordpress index page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site and I want to change certain CSS values in the header.php on the index page only. I have a div which is 100% width and border bottom to add an underline to the header.php

```
<div class="nav"> 

   ...content to create nav-bar ...

    <div class="hr"></div> <!-- remove on index.php -->

</div>
```

I don't want it to show, or affect anything on the index.php.  (I don't want to target another header.php file for this one small thing)

Comment: use `is_page()`: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress has a template tag called [`body_class`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) which is used to create contextual CSS hooks.

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

You can then use it in your CSS as follows:

```
.blog {}
.blog.home {}
/** if blog index is a page **/
.page.blog {}
```

see [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) for the rather extensive list of possible output.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, by default, in a Wordpress site, the `body` element has a `home` class for the front page.

So in your CSS you could try the following:

```
.home .nav .hr { display:none; }
```